# Azure Mobile Services SDK available via Gradle for Android?

Tags: android, azure, gradle, android-studio, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to install the SDK (Azure mobile services) for use on Android.

I do notice from the main tutorials and links it seems you have to download it, surely its available via Gradle ??

I have tried searching for it and I can't find it.

Is this not the correct way of installing it rather than downloading the files and adding to the class path ??

Look forward to any ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a Gradle option to install the Azure Mobile Services SDK. Please consider creating a new feature request at http://aka.ms/amsfeedback to have this support added to the SDK.

And you're correct, for now the way to install it is to download the .jar file and add it to the "libs" folder (or the class path) of your app.

Comment: And you believe this is an acceptable solution from your company's point of view, when entering on a huge platform such as Android? You need to come to terms with the platform's usage and best practices, not your own. But there you have it, Microsoft is still stuck in the past with outdated offerings.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, try this:

```
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2'
```